# Matlab GUI: Dynamically changing the popup menu

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a `GUI` that I want to add a `popup menu` to it.
The `popup menu` fields that should be shown are saved in the file `targets.txt`.

When I open my program, I want the `popup menu` to include the lines from the mentioned file above.
**I'm doing this because I want the** `popup menu` **to change dynamically in the program. Since it will include directories paths that the user entered in another field, I'm saving the directories paths in a file, and each time a user enters a folder, I set the** `popup menu` **according to the file.** (I did it and it works fine)

Since `function myFunction_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)` is called only **after** calling the `"create function"` of each component of the `GUI`, I *couldn't* do the initialization in the `"opening function"` of the program. Instead, I had to to something like this:

```
function databaseMenu_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if ispc&&isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
handles.databaseMenuObject=hObject; % (1) see below
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

**(1)**: I save the popup menu object in handles so that I can use it in the opening function.

And then, in the opening function I can do:

```
fid_r = fopen('targets.txt', 'r');
C = textscan(fid_r, '%s');
set(handles.databaseMenuObject,'String', C{1});
```

So, when someone adds a new `"database"` folder in the program, the `popup menu` *changes* (I add the folder that was chosen by the user to the file, and then I set the `popup menu` to have its field from the file (the function above). So it'll look like that:

[image: The program after the user entered two folders]

I don't like the design of my code, and I couldn't figure out how to do it in a different way, is there a way to make the `"create function"` of the `"popup menu"` to be called **after** the `"opening function"` of the program? Or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Perhaps it is just me, but I get a bit lost in this question. Could you perhaps summarize what you want to ask at the top of the question?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I edited it, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background**

A few things that may be helpful:

- You can define additional functions as needed within a GUI; you are not limited to the callbacks defined.
- Tagging figure elements makes them easy to find from any callback.
- `gcbf` returns the current callback figure.
- `union` can return the union of cell arrays of strings.

**Suggestions**

Here is how I might write such a function. This puts everything in one place, the function can be called from anywhere within your GUI, it automatically updates the cached list, and eliminates any duplicate entries.

You would call this code at the end of your init code, as well as the callback for adding folders. The *Tag* can be set by right-clicking and setting properties within GUIDE.

```
updatePopupMenu()
  popupMenuHandle = findobj(gcbf,'Tag','myPopupMenuTag');
  popupMenuContents = get(popupMenuHandle,'String');

  % Initialization
  if isempty(popupMenuContests)
    fid_r = fopen('targets.txt', 'r');
    C = textscan(fid_r, '%s');
    popupMenuContents = C{1};
  end

  % Join
  otherFields = howeverYouGetFieldsFromOtherList();
  combinedContents = union(popupMenuContents, otherFields);

  % Save
  set(popupMenuHandle,'String', combinedContents);
  fid_w = fopen('targets.txt','w+');
  for i = 1:length(combinedContents)
    fprintf(fid_w,'%s\n',combinedContents{i}); 
  end
  fclose(fid_w);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright I now understand what you want to achieve, though I am not sure whether I understand the problem I hope this helps:

Judging from the description this seems like a logical order for things to happen:

1: Initalization, just initialize everything, you already know that you will have a dropdown menu but you just don't know the content yet. Therefore just start with a defaultoption or empty (possibly invisible).

2: Update, As soon as the users saves new input, you update the list.

Comment: I can't start with a default empty menu because I want the previous folders entered by the user in the previous run to be saved (that's why I use a file to save the data) So the list is updated even when you close and reopen the program (It works, I just need a better way to do it)

Comment: @MarounMaroun, "better" in what sense?

Comment: In the sense of design, I think it can be done in a "more readable" way